# Prove: If $p=p^*+e_1$ and $q=q^*+e_2$, then the relative error...

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods

If $p=p^*+e_1$ and $q=q^*+e_2$, then the relative error in the product of $p*q$ is roughly equal to the sum of individual relative errors in p and q.

Here is my attempt:
We want to show $$ \frac{\mid pq-p^*q^* \mid}{\mid pq \mid}= \frac{\mid p-p^* \mid}{\mid p \mid}+\frac{\mid q-q^* \mid}{\mid q \mid}$$
$$RHS= \frac{\mid p^*+e_1-p^* \mid}{\mid p \mid}+\frac{\mid q^*+e_2-q^* \mid}{\mid q \mid}$$
$$= \frac{\mid e_1\mid}{\mid p \mid}+\frac{\mid e_2 \mid}{\mid q \mid}$$
$$= \frac{\mid q*e_1\mid}{\mid p \mid}+\frac{\mid p*e_2 \mid}{\mid q \mid}$$
$$= \frac{\mid q*e_1+p*e_2\mid}{\mid pq \mid}$$
$$= \frac{\mid q(p-p^*)+p(q-q^*)\mid}{\mid pq \mid}$$
$$= \frac{\mid qp-qp^*+pq-pq^*\mid}{\mid pq \mid}$$
$$= \frac{\mid 2pq-pq^*-qp^*\mid}{\mid pq \mid}$$

Here is where I get stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$pq=(p^*+e_1)(q^*+e_2)=p^* q^*\left(1+\frac{e_1}{p^*}\right)\left(1+\frac{e_2}{q^*}\right)$$
Take logarithms 
$$\log(pq)=\log(p^* q^*)+\log\left(1+\frac{e_1}{p^*}\right)+\log\left(1+\frac{e_2}{q^*}\right)$$
Using Taylor
$$\log(pq)\sim\log(p^* q^*)+\frac{e_1}{p^*}+\frac{e_2}{q^*}\implies \frac{pq}{p^* q^*}\sim \exp\left(\frac{e_1}{p^*}+\frac{e_2}{q^*}\right)$$ Use Taylor again
$$\frac{pq}{p^* q^*}\sim 1+\frac{e_1}{p^*}+\frac{e_2}{q^*}\implies\frac{pq-p^* q^*}{p^* q^*}\sim \frac{e_1}{p^*}+\frac{e_2}{q^*}$$

Comment: The issue I have with this is that the relative error is defined as $\frac{\mid p-p^* \mid}{\mid p \mid}$ where $p$ is the actual number and $p^*$ is the approximation. You define it as $\frac{\mid p-p^* \mid}{\mid p^* \mid}$.

Comment: @MANONMARS45. It is the same.